Justice of the Peace Marriage & Divorced - Is Godparent possible?
My sister was married by a Justice of the Peace; but, is now divorced. I would like her to be my daughter's Godmother when we have her Baptized in a few months. Is that allowed?

Welcome to C.SE.  Your question can be answered differently by different Christian denominations, so we require questions like this to be scoped accordingly by including in the question the perspective that you are asking for.  So please edit your question to add whether you are asking in the context of the Catholic Church, the Eastern Orthodox church, the Anglican church, etc.  Also please add the appropriate tag.

Well, you did not specify your denomination. So I will give you the answer for my denomination. So in the eastern orthodox church these are the requirements for being a godparent. (Koumbaros/a)

Must be a Baptised Orthodox Christian.
Must be in full sacramental communion.
Must be in good standing (requirements for this vary by region)
If married, it must have been an Orthodox Marriage.
If divorced, even civilly, must have been granted an ecclesiastical divorce
They cannot be a minor, the parent of the child, or a non-Orthodox Christian.

In some Orthodox churches (i.e. Serbian, Greek), usually the best man (кум, koumbaros) or the bridesmaid (kuma, кума, koumbara) at a couple's wedding are the ones to act as godparents to the first child, or to all of the children of the marriage.
